# How to insert character in the beginning of all items in a list, while excluding specific items, based on another list?

Tags: python, list

I have a list1 (which can be much longer than this one) :

```
data_into_list = ["a", "good", "with", "amor", "and", "friand"]
```

and I want to add a hashtag ('#') only to certain items, excluding some, based on another list2 : if a word from list2 is in list1, no hashtag is added to it.

Like :

excluded_words = ["a", "with", "and"]

(*I tried several solutions, but since I'm rather a beginner in Python, I can't find a correct way to do it. I tried to add a hashtag to all the words in the list, convert it to string, and then to do a substitution, via a loop and .replace. I also tried to use a dictionnary, and use re.sub. But in both cases, it doesn't match the exact character (it removes the # not only to the "a" item, but also on all items that begin with "a", like "amor" in my list). And it seems that a dictionnary can't use regex, to match the exact character, as far as I understand...*)

In any case, it seems more logical to do a list comparison, and exclude some items based on a second list, but I can't manage to find how...

Thx in advance

**Edit, here are one of my failed solutions :**

```
import re

# opening the file in read mode
my_file = open("LastPrompt.txt", "r")
  
# reading the file
data = my_file.read()
  
# split each word into a list
data_into_list = data.replace('\n', ' ').split()

string = '#'

#add hashtags on every words
addhashtag = [string + x for x in data_into_list]


#convert list to string -> needed to be saved in .txt
hashtags = ' '.join(map(str, addhashtag))

#replace every undesired word with # by the same word without #
for r in (("#A", "A"), ("#is", "is"), ("#a", "a"), ("#with", "with")):
     hashtag = hashtag.replace(*r)
```

Comment: Can you share the solutions you have tried?

Comment: And can you add a sample second list with the expected results that would produce?

Comment: Yes, it's edited :)

Comment: I think my answer below should cover what you need.

Comment: The main difference between my approach and yours is that I effectively filter for the exclude list as I build the equivalent of your `addhashtag` instead of trying to remove the hashtags afterwards, which makes it a lot easier to do and more efficient.

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help. SO can be rough. Someone presumably thought you didn't have enough details or didn't do enough research or something like that. Your edited question is better, for sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert the second list into a set and look up each string from the first list in that set.

This will do the trick:

```
data_into_list = ["a", "good", "with", "amor", "and", "friand"]
excluded_words = ["a", "with", "and"]

excluded_set = set(excluded_words)
new_list = [
    item if item in excluded_set else "#" + item
    for item in data_into_list
]
print(new_list)
```

Output: `['a', '#good', 'with', '#amor', 'and', '#friand']`

EDIT: updated to use the exclude list from your updated question.